# How do you return the out variables to a nodejs application on calling a stored procedure

Tags: node.js, oracle, api, plsql, oracle11g

I am new at this and was having a problem. I have stored procedure that was created by the DB admin of our company and there are many out variables in it. So I am calling the stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE
  ln_order_qty        NUMBER;
  ln_in_proc_qty_hr   NUMBER;
  ln_procd_hr_mass    NUMBER;
  ln_in_proc_qty      NUMBER;
  ln_wip              NUMBER;
  ln_qa               NUMBER;
  ln_packing          NUMBER;
  ln_dispatchable_qty NUMBER;
  ln_despatched_qty   NUMBER;
  ln_finished_qty     NUMBER;
  ln_balance_qty      NUMBER;
  ln_bal_disp_qty     NUMBER;
BEGIN
  CRMDBA.C1DVX007('9514593782',
                  '1',
                  1,
                  ln_order_qty,
                  ln_in_proc_qty_hr,
                  ln_procd_hr_mass,
                  
                  ln_in_proc_qty,
                  ln_wip,
                  ln_qa,
                  ln_packing,
                  ln_dispatchable_qty,
                  ln_despatched_qty,
                  ln_finished_qty,
                  ln_ba lance_qty,
                  ln_bal_disp_qty);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ln_order_qty);
END;
The problem with this is that DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE just prints line in the database. The procedure does not return any values which can be used in the backend. However it gives values to outvariables.

How can I extract these outvariables from the procedure so that I can use them in the backend?

The stored procedure itself is this:

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CRMDBA.C1DVX007 ( ls_id_order IN VARCHAR2,
    ln_item_no IN NUMBER,
    ln_part_order IN NUMBER,
    ln_order_qty OUT NUMBER,
    ln_in_proc_qty_hr OUT NUMBER,
    ln_procd_hr_mass OUT NUMBER,
    ln_in_proc_qty OUT NUMBER,
    ln_wip OUT NUMBER,
    ln_qa OUT NUMBER,
    ln_packing OUT NUMBER,
    ln_dispatchable_qty OUT NUMBER,
    ln_despatched_qty OUT NUMBER ,
    ln_finished_qty OUT NUMBER,
    ln_balance_qty OUT NUMBER,
    ln_bal_disp_qty OUT NUMBER
    
    )
    IS
    
    BEGIN
    ln_in_proc_qty_hr := 0 ;
    ln_procd_hr_mass := 0 ;
    ln_in_proc_qty := 0 ;
    ln_wip := 0 ;
    ln_qa := 0 ;
    ln_packing := 0 ;
    ln_dispatchable_qty := 0 ;
    ln_despatched_qty := 0 ;
    ln_finished_qty := 0 ;
    ln_balance_qty := 0 ;
    ln_bal_disp_qty := 0;
    
    
    
    --CALCULATION OF ORDER QNTY
    BEGIN
    SELECT por_ms_prt_order
    INTO ln_order_qty
    FROM v_part_order
    WHERE por_wo_no = ls_id_order
    AND por_item_no = ln_item_no
    AND por_id_part_order = ln_part_order;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
    END;
    
    
    
    ----HR AT HSM
    BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(SUM(APP_MS_PIECE_ACT),0)
    INTO ln_in_proc_qty_hr
    FROM kpofp.t_a_prod_piece@tskcrm_kpois_dbl
    WHERE APP_id_order = ls_id_order
    AND APP_id_order_item = ln_item_no
    AND APP_id_part_order = 1
    AND APP_cd_prod_grp = '25'
    AND APP_cd_st_piece IN ('AC', 'LN', 'AA', 'HB','HC','IN')
    AND APP_cd_company = '1000'
    AND APP_cd_dept = '117'
    AND APP_id_proc_cntr = '01';
    
    ln_in_proc_qty_hr := ROUND(ln_in_proc_qty_hr);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
    END;
    
    
    
    ----HR AT CRM
    BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(SUM(hrc_ms_piece_act),0)
    INTO ln_procd_hr_mass
    FROM v_hr_coil
    WHERE hrc_id_order = ls_id_order
    AND hrc_id_order_item = ln_item_no
    AND hrc_id_part_order = ln_part_order
    AND hrc_cd_st_piece IN ('PB','PC','PJ','PD');
    
    ln_procd_hr_mass:= ROUND(ln_procd_hr_mass);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
    END;
    
    
    
    ---INPROCESS QTY CR
    BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(SUM(ccl_ms_piece_actl),0)
    INTO ln_in_proc_qty
    FROM v_cold_coil
    WHERE ccl_id_order = ls_id_order
    AND ccl_id_order_item = ln_item_no
    AND ccl_id_order_part = ln_part_order
    AND ccl_cd_status IN ('AB','AC','AJ,''AD','LB','LC','LJ','LD','GB','GC','GJ','GD','RB','RC','RJ','RD','XB','XC','XJ','XD',
    'YB','YC','YJ','YD','DB','DC','DJ','DD','PP') ;
    
    ln_in_proc_qty := ROUND(ln_in_proc_qty);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
    END;
    
    
    
    ----QA AT CRM
    BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(SUM(ccl_ms_piece_actl),0)
    INTO ln_qa
    FROM v_cold_coil
    WHERE ccl_id_order = ls_id_order
    AND ccl_id_order_item = ln_item_no
    AND ccl_id_order_part = ln_part_order
    AND (ccl_cd_status LIKE '%Q'
    OR ccl_cd_status IN ('AP','LP','GP','RP','XP','YP','DP')) ;
    
    ln_qa := ROUND(ln_qa);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
    END;
    
    
    
    ----PACKING AT CRM
    BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(SUM(ccl_ms_piece_actl),0)
    INTO ln_packing
    FROM v_cold_coil
    WHERE ccl_id_order = ls_id_order
    AND ccl_id_order_item = ln_item_no
    AND ccl_id_order_part = ln_part_order
    AND ccl_cd_status IN ('CB','CC','CJ','CD','CP','TB','TC','TJ','TD','TP','MB','MC','MJ','MD','MP') ;
    
    ln_packing:= ROUND(ln_packing);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
    END;
    
    
    
    ----DESPATCHABLE AT CRM
    BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(SUM(ccl_ms_piece_actl),0)
    INTO ln_dispatchable_qty
    FROM v_cold_coil
    WHERE ccl_id_order = ls_id_order
    AND ccl_id_order_item = ln_item_no
    AND ccl_id_order_part = ln_part_order
    AND ccl_cd_status IN ('VB','VC','VD','VP') ;
    
    ln_dispatchable_qty:= ROUND(ln_dispatchable_qty);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
    END;
    
    
    
    ----DESPATCHED AT CRM
    BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(SUM(ccl_ms_piece_actl),0)
    INTO ln_despatched_qty
    FROM v_cold_coil
    WHERE ccl_id_order = ls_id_order
    AND ccl_id_order_item = ln_item_no
    AND ccl_id_order_part = ln_part_order
    AND ccl_cd_status ='VL';
    
    ln_despatched_qty:= ROUND(ln_despatched_qty);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
    END;
    
    
    
    
    ln_balance_qty := ( NVL(ln_order_qty,0) - NVL(ln_in_proc_qty_hr,0)- NVL(ln_procd_hr_mass ,0)
    - NVL(ln_in_proc_qty,0)-NVL(ln_qa,0)-nvl(ln_packing,0)-NVL(ln_despatched_qty,0)
    - NVL(ln_dispatchable_qty,0) ) ;
    
    
    
    
    END;
    /
```

Here I am trying to get value in the nodejs application through a controller in the following ways:

This is the query part of it:

```
 export const infoHR3 = async () => {
      try {
        const sql =
    
      ` 
      
      Declare
      ln_order_qty  NUMBER;
    
    ln_in_proc_qty_hr  NUMBER;
    
    ln_procd_hr_mass  NUMBER;
    
    ln_in_proc_qty  NUMBER;
    
    ln_wip  NUMBER;
    
    ln_qa  NUMBER;
    
    ln_packing  NUMBER;
    
    ln_dispatchable_qty  NUMBER;
    
    ln_despatched_qty  NUMBER ;
    
    ln_finished_qty  NUMBER;
    
    ln_balance_qty  NUMBER;
    
    ln_bal_disp_qty  NUMBER;
    
      BEGIN
    
      CRMDBA.C1DVX007('9514593782','1',1,ln_order_qty,ln_in_proc_qty_hr,ln_procd_hr_mass,
      ln_in_proc_qty,ln_wip,ln_qa,ln_packing,ln_dispatchable_qty,ln_despatched_qty,ln_finished_qty,ln_balance_qty,ln_bal_disp_qty);
      dbms_output.put_line(ln_order_qty);
         END;  `;
    
         
         return await query(sql);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error.InternalServerError("Error!");
      }
    
     
    };

This is the model:

    function getinfoHR3Table() {
      return infoHR3();
    }
    
    
    export const ProcessModel = {
      getProcess,
      getReason,
      getinfoHR1Table,
      getinfoHR2Table,
      getinfoCR1Table,
      getinfoCR2Table,
      getinfoHR3Table
    };

This is the controller:

    export const getinfoHR3Table = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      try {
        
        const results: any = await ProcessModel.getinfoHR3Table();
        
        
        return res.status(200).json(results);
       
      } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json(error);
      }
    };

The problem is I am getting blank value in the result. How do I extract out variables and return them when calling a stored procedure??
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70389884/edit) your original question with these details rather than creating a new duplicate question.

Comment: Don't catch `OTHERS` and ignore the errors. You should catch the expected errors (like `NO_DATA_FOUND`) and handle them and then if there are other errors you should let the code fail so that you can debug it (or if you must have the procedure succeed then catch the errors and log them somewhere) but just ignoring them is bad practice.

Comment: MT0 if you have answer to this then please share what do you mean dont catch others??

Comment: I don't have an answer for your node.js question; however, on the Oracle side, the procedure your DBA created catches the `OTHERS` exceptions and ignores the exception and that is bad practice.